# How to define Integer array in Flask Migration to create new Table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I want to create Table using Flask Migration tool for my Postgresql Database.

I have written my flask model as follow:

```
from flask.ext.security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, utils
class AdminUser(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    allow_center_list = db.Column(db.ARRAY(db.Integer))
    admin_profile_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('admin_profile.id'))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    modified = db.Column(db.DateTime(), default=datetime.now)

    user = db.relationship("User", back_populates="admin_user")
    admin_profile = db.relationship("AdminProfile", back_populates="admin_user")
```

I want to user integer array for allow_center_list column.

When I try execute "flask db upgrade" command (after executing init and migrate command), I am getting error as follow:

```
sa.Column('allow_center_list', sa.ARRAY(Integer()), nullable=True),NameError: name 'Integer' is not defined
```

Please guide me how we can define Integer array in Flask SQLAlchemy model.

Comment: Surely it should be `db.Integer`, as you have used everywhere else?

Comment: I wrote db.Integer (even I tried Integer also), getting same error for both the cases.

Answer (score 4):

This might be similar to this [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36868914/1216837).

Try `sa.Integer()` instead.

Comment: Great. Could you please click "accept" on my answer.